# Wi-Fi always requires manual choice to select desired network

Tags: macos, mac, network, wifi

We have Wi-Fi at home but each time I turn on my Mac it goes to an unlocked Wi-Fi not our own and I have to go into Wi-Fi on the menu bar to select our own home Wi-Fi. I just want to eliminate those competing options and save the step of always choosing our home network.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences → Network → Wi-Fi → Advanced… and remove the network from the list of preferred networks.

[image]